# How to make select group available to choose after selecting specific value in HTML

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

**Scenario :**

Assume that..a html web with 2 select group:

select group 1 has `['value0'],['value1'],['value2'],['value3'];`

- if select `value0` , select group 2 appears with all greyed out
  values.
- if select `value1` , select group 2 appears `['value1_1'],['value1_2']`, other value greyed out
- if select `value2`, select group 2 appears `['value2_1'], ['value2_2']`, other values greyed out.
- if select `value3` , select group 2 appears `['value3_1'],['value3_2']`, other value greyed out.

I have searched many data but still not what I need...

Could anyone help?

Comment: please edit the question and write your code

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, could this be like what you're looking for?

```js
$('#one').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#two option').each(function(){ 
  $('.one_one').removeAttr("disabled");
  $('.two_two').attr("disabled","true");
  $('.three_three').attr("disabled","true");
  });
  }
  
  if ($(this).val() == '2') {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#two option').each(function(){ 
  $('.one_one').attr("disabled","true");
  $('.two_two').removeAttr("disabled");
  $('.three_three').attr("disabled","true");
  });
  }
  
  if ($(this).val() == '3') {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#two option').each(function(){ 
  $('.one_one').attr("disabled","true");
  $('.two_two').attr("disabled","true");
  $('.three_three').removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
<option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">select 1</option>
  <option value="2">select 2</option>
  <option value="3">select 3</option>

</select>

<select disabled id="two">
  <option class ="one_one" value="value1_1">value1_1</option>
  <option class ="one_one" value="value1_2">value1_2</option>
  <option class ="two_two" value="value2_1">value2_1</option>
  <option class ="two_two" value="value2_2">value2_2</option>
  <option class ="three_three" value="value3_1">value3_1</option>
  <option class ="three_three" value="value3_2">value3_2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank You , you solve my question and straight to the problems!!! It's perfect. =D

Comment: @RichardKok glad that helped! happy coding!